# How can I include a loop to validate a file exists on a remote host until the statement is true in KSH?

Tags: file, validation, ksh, host, exists

so I am trying to validate if there is a file that exists on a remote host, if so, say valid. If it doesn't, then say it's invalid. I've got that to work in a function. However, I can't seem to come up with a loop that would confirm this statement is true to move on with the script. Or, after messing around, it does move on with the script but it doesn't correctly validate the file to repeat asking a question. After many failed attempts, this is what I've come up with.

```
    validate_d()
    {
        valid="file exists"
        invalid="file doesn't exist"
        ssh -q *host* [[ -f $userpath]] && echo "valid" || echo "invalid";
    }
        while (*this is my script asking the user if they input the correct path, if not, keep asking for correct path*)
        done
    validate_d
        until [[ this statement is confirmed that the file exists ]]; do
            print $invalid
            read userpath
        done
```

In the until statement, I can't figure out how to validate the file exists and the condition is true. Should I be using an until or while with if? Any kind of feedback would be a big help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be quite a few ways to a) test for the existence of a remote file and b) how to pass back a valid/invalid code.

Here's a bare bones example:

```
while true
do
    printf "Enter fullpath of file to check for: "
    read userpath
    ssh -q hostname [ -f "${userpath:-undefined}" ]
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'valid' && break
    echo 'invalid'
done
```

The `[ -f ${userpath} ]` is executed remotely on the host named 'remotehost'.

If the file represented by `${userpath}` is found then a `0` (true) is returned else a `1` (false) is returned.

The `$?` contains our return code from the `ssh/-f ${userpath}` construct.

If the file is found (`$?=0`) we echo 'valid' and break out of the loop, else we print 'invalid' and perform the next iteration of the loop.

Assume the files `/tmp/test1` and `/tmp/test2` do not exist on the remotehost, but the file `/tmp/test3` does exist, running the above code snippet looks like:

```
$ while true
do
    printf "Enter fullpath of file to check for: "
    read userpath
    ssh -q hostname [ -f "${userpath:-undefined}" ]
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'valid' && break
    echo 'invalid'
done
Enter fullpath of file to check for: /tmp/test1
invalid
Enter fullpath of file to check for: /tmp/test2
invalid
Enter fullpath of file to check for: /tmp/test3
valid
$
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius! It worked!! Thank you so much.